# Не работает проверка пустого поля ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

У меня есть записи, у каждой записи есть поле добавленное через acf. Блок с этими записями дублируется на многих страницах сайта. В блоке выводится: тайтл записи, миниатюра и то самое поле выведенное через acf. Мне нужно выводить в этот блок только те записи у которых поле acf заполнено. Работает все кроме этой самой проверки на заполненное поле acf, не могу понять в чем проблема. Данный код выводит нормально посты только в файле index.php, на остальных страницах get_field возвращает null

Сам код который в файле в template-parts:

```php
    <?php if( !is_page_template('page-indianwedding.php') ) : ?>
        <?php
            $query_args = array(
                'category__in' => 5
            );
            $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
            if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $var = get_field('story_review_text', $query->post->ID); var_dump($var); ?>
                <?php if(isset($var)) : ?>
                    <div class="feedbacks-slide">
                        <div class="decor mb-60">
                            <div class="decor__row">
                                <span class="decor__line decor__line--left"></span>
                                <div class="decor__photo">
                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query->post->ID, 'full'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <span class="decor__line decor__line--right"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feedbacks-slide__content text-sub mb-60  text-center"><?php echo $var; ?></div>
                        <p class="feedbacks-slide__name text-h3 feedbacks-arrow text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="feedbacks-slider__arrow feedbacks-slider__arrow--prev" ></button>
                            <span>-<?php the_title(); ?>-</span>
                            <button type="button" class="feedbacks-slider__arrow feedbacks-slider__arrow--next" ></button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.feedbacks-slide -->
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: Скрин админки как создаю поле story_review_text]

Comment: Ну попробуй глянуть, что у тебя в переменных. Я конечно в программировании новичок но чаще всего советуют именно это

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич я же написала, что она null возвращает)

Comment: А, ну да. Ведь в коде только одна переменная

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич я вас не очень понимаю, ведь у меня проблема именно в get_field

Comment: Действительно странно. Ведь результат выполнения функции никак не зависит от переданных аргументов...

Comment: Записи это что? То что вы выводите в цикле? Тогда почему проверку на существования `story_review_text` вы делаете вне цикла у какойто другой выборки? Раз у каждой записи есть поле, то и проверять нужно каждую запись или через WP_Query доставить сразу все записи у которых поле не пустое.

Comment: Так может null потому что query-id пустой (там где вы объявляете переменную)?

Comment: @Алексей дело в том, что в цикле я тоже проверку пыталась вывести и он все равно был пустой..я над этим вопросом уже третий день сижу, перебрала и все варианты расположения и все циклы, результат один и тот же

Comment: @eugene_vandar я и через $post->ID вывести пыталась, пост как бы глобальная..толку никакого

Comment: @Alexa но у вас же аргументы и объект идут после этой переменной, а должны быть перед ней. А во-вторых, вы же получите массив с ID (если я не ошибаюсь), поэтому скорее всего это поле должно проверяться уже в самом цикле

Comment: Может стоит заглянуть внутрь $post и $query и посмотреть что там такое глобальное лежит? Возможно поможет `var_dump()`?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич она делает var_dump в 4 строке, правда всей переменной, а не ID-шников

Comment: Круто. Осталось подставить в него нужную переменную, да.

Comment: @eugene_vandar  ок, допустим перенесла после цикла, выглядит следующим образом:
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $var = get_field('story_review_text', $query->post->ID); var_dump($var); ?>
что тоже выводит null

Comment: @Alexa а что может лежать в глобальной переменной $post?)))

Comment: Интересно - сколько времени понадобится, после решения этой задачи, чтобы понять почему слетела пагинация и на некоторых страницах выводится 10 записей, а на некоторых 2?

Comment: @Alexa Покажите как вы создаете поле `story_review_text`, а также полный код шаблона - template-parts это часть шаблона покажите где вы его вызываете.

Comment: @Алексей А лучше бекап всего сайта залить в облако, лишь бы не делать вар дамп одной переменной, да?

Comment: @Алексей это полный код шаблона в template-parts. Вызываю в файлах просто через стандартный <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/reviews-block' ); ?>. Скрин создания acf добавила

Comment: @Alexa сложно сказать почему.Вы уверенны что у постов этой категории это поле заполнено? Проверьте содержит ли $query вообще посты. Уберите пока лишние проверки. А вообще потратьте время на настройку xdebug, в интернете есть куча статей для любого редактора кода, с ним гораздо легче разобраться в проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Автор, почему нужно именно засовывать get_field в переменную?

Я бы попробовал так:

```
<?php if(!empty(get_field('story_review_text'))) { ?>
<div class="feedbacks-slide__content text-sub mb-60  text-center"><?php the_field('story_review_text');?></div>
<?};?>
```